# Using AJAX with MVC 5 and Umbraco

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, umbraco

I need to use ajax in a partial view to call a function in a mvc controller to return a calculation.

FYI, I am using MVC 5 and Umbraco 7.

I currently have the ajax code within the partial view (will want to move this to a js file at some point).

Here is the ajax code:

```
function GetTime(name) {
    var result = "";

    $.ajax({
        url: '/TimeDifference/GetTimeDifference',
        //url: '@Url.Action("GetTimeDifference", "TimeDifference")',
        type: 'GET',
        //data: JSON.stringify({ location: name }),
        data: ({ location: name }),
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        cache: false,
        success: function (msg) {
            result = msg;
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert(xhr.status);
      }
    });

    return result;
}
```

Here is the Controller:

```
public class TimeDifferenceController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
      [HttpGet]
       public JsonResult GetTimeDifference(string location)
        {
            DateTime utc = DateTime.UtcNow;
            string timeZoneName = GetTimeZoneName(location);
            TimeZoneInfo gmt = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("GMT Standard Time");
            TimeZoneInfo local = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(timeZoneName);

            TimeSpan utcOffset = gmt.GetUtcOffset(utc);
            TimeSpan localOffset = local.GetUtcOffset(utc);
            TimeSpan difference = localOffset - utcOffset;

            return Json(Convert.ToInt16(difference.TotalMinutes),JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

           }
}
```

The above code gives me a 404 Not Found Error:

```
Request URL:http://localhost:100/TimeDifference/GetTimeDifference?location=BVI&_=1511949514552
Request Method:GET
Status Code:404 Not Found
Remote Address:[::1]:100
```

If I use:
url: '@Url.Action("GetTimeDifference", "TimeDifference")'

The @Url.Action("GetTimeDifference", "TimeDifference") is Null so it doesn't go anywhere.

I have also tried:

```
@Html.Hidden("URLName", Url.Action("GetTimeDifference", "TimeDifference"))
...
url:  $("#URLName").val()
```

Url is still Null.

I have added entries in to the Global.asax.cs for routing i.e.

```
routes.MapRoute(
                 "Default", // Route name
                 "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                 new { controller = "TimeDifference", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
             );
```

This doesn't seem to do anything.

I have gone through a lot of the questions raised previously and amended as per suggestions but nothing seems to work.

As I am new to this I'm sure it something very simple I am missing.

Many thanks,
HH

Comment: I recommend reading up on the [UmbracoApiController](https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/reference/routing/webapi/). It maps routes automatically for you and helps give you access to useful things like the `UmbracoHelper`. If you struggle with getting it working, please say so and I'll post an answer showing how it works.

Comment: @Harvey - thank you for you reply you were spot on with the UmbracoAPIcontroller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your controller won't be wired automatically, and I don't think the global.asax.cs file will work either. You can either register a custom route for your controller in an Umbraco Startup Handler: https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/reference/routing/custom-routes or you can create your controller as an Umbraco WebApi Controller, which is designed for stuff like this: https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Reference/Routing/WebApi/.

Umbraco WebAPI controllers get wired in automatically and will return either JSON or XML automatically depending on what the calling client asks for.

Comment: Thank you also for your reply, I went down the WebApi route.